# how to deal with misscomunication and documentation besides agile meth?

Tags: workflow, documentation, communication, code-testing

I'm looking for advice on how to improve the efficiency of my IT team and streamline our development pipeline. We currently use agile methodologies, but I'm wondering if there are other practical solutions we should consider.

Some specific pain points we've experienced include slow code review times, difficulty in reproducing and debugging production issues, and communication breakdowns between teams. We also struggle with balancing the need for quick feature delivery with maintaining code quality and scalability after design release.

Are there any best practices or tools that have helped other teams address these issues? How can we better coordinate with other teams and ensure everyone is working towards the same goals? Any advice on improving the overall workflow and pipeline management would be greatly appreciated.

Our IT team has been struggling with collaboration and communication issues despite adopting agile methodologies. We've noticed a lack of communication and missing documentation between teams that has resulted in delays and errors in our pipeline. We believe that automation could be a potential solution, but we're not sure where to start.

We would like to hear about other teams' experiences and practical solutions for improving collaboration within IT teams

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like your IT team has been experiencing some difficulties with respect to code knowledge sharing, which is actually a pretty common problem many teams face.

You could maybe try looking into a tool like [Swimm](https://swimm.io/?utm_source=IPE_circuit&utm_medium=paid_pub&utm_campaign=IPE-march&utm_content=gm-test), which builds on a docs-as-code approach. You can explicitly reference live code from your repo within the docs. Being code-coupled this way means it also sends out alerts whenever there are code changes so that the documentation can be updated and remains in sync.

You can also create an ordered view (think Spotify playlists) of markdown, videos, external links, and existing docs if need be, to communicate all relevant knowledge regarding your existing codebase. This is particularly helpful when it comes to keeping your teams on the same page regarding the code and any subsequent updates made.

Hope that helps.

###### Reference: [Walk developers through your codebase with Documentation Playlists](https://swimm.io/blog/documentation-playlists?utm_source=IPE_circuit&utm_medium=paid_pub&utm_campaign=IPE-march&utm_content=gm-test)